# i tried an API request but it is giving me this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

i tried fetching an api request from `https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?` but it is getting back this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'". here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import suggestSearch from "../../Apis/suggestSearch";

const getSuggestions = () => {

 const [autoSearchData, setAutoSearch] = useState("");

 const getAutocomplete = async () => {
    const response = await suggestSearch.get("", {
      params: {
        q: searchQuery,
      }
    });
    setAutoSearch(response.data[1]);
    console.log(setAutoSearch);
    console.log(autoSearchData);
  };
}
```

here is the suggestSearch code

```
import axios from "axios";
import jsonpAdapter from "axios-jsonp";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?",
  adapter: jsonpAdapter,
  params: {
    hl: "en", // Language
    ds: "yt", // Restrict lookup to youtube
    client: "youtube" // force youtube style response, i.e. jsonp
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because you are referring to an asset that no longer exists. Check your API request link to see if it is still a valid asset.

Answer (score 0):

From the `baseURL` I'm inferring that you're trying to do a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request.
For such a request to succeed in `axios`, you will have to import the `querystring` module and then do `axios.post(baseURL,qs.stringify({data}),config)`.
 In this case, `const qs=require('querystring');`.